# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pair' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been fumbling through trying to learn scripting for google sheets. The following returns the correct results. But, it stops my script and shows the following error. Any help would be much appreciated.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pair' of undefined

```
  var sh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SCRIPT_DATA");
  var requestOptions = {
  'method': 'GET',
 https://api.incscan.io/pdex/overview,
{
start: 1,
limit: 5000,

  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};
var url='https://api.incscan.io/pdex/overview';

var result= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
var txt= result.getContentText();
var d=JSON.parse(txt);

    for (var i=0; i<100;i++)

{
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 7).setValue(d.perPair[i].pair);
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 8).setValue(d.perPair[i].liquidity);
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 9).setValue(d.perPair[i].volume);
}
  sh1.getRange(2, 12).setValue(d.liquidity);   
  sh1.getRange(2, 13).setValue(d.allTimeVolume);
```

Comment: The error means for for some value of `i`, `d.perPair[i]` is `undefined`.

Comment: can you `console.log(d)` and `console.log(d.perPair[i])` ?

Comment: I'm completely new to this, so I'm not 100% sure where I would add the console.log(d) or console.log(d.perPair[i]). I don't even know what that would be doing exactly. However, I think I found the source of the problem. There are only 71 results, so "i<100" is the problem since everything after 71 is undefined. Is there a way to write that without knowing how many results there are to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop on the available data

```
for (let i = 0; i < d.perPair.length; i++) {
  sh1.getRange(i + 2, 7).setValue(d.perPair[i].pair);
  sh1.getRange(i + 2, 8).setValue(d.perPair[i].liquidity);
  sh1.getRange(i + 2, 9).setValue(d.perPair[i].volume);
}
```