# find this error in my code TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null (line 5, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

```
function prices() {

  var scraperSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("prices")
  
  var lrow = scraperSheet.getLastRow();
  
  for (var i=2;i<=lrow;i++)
  {
    
    var regEx = /<span id="priceblock_dealprice.*<\/span>/gi
  
    var getContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.amazon.in/"+scraperSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue()).getContentText().trim();
    var price = getContent.match(regEx)
    price = price[0];
    price = price.replace('<span id="priceblock_dealprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockDealPriceString">',"")
    .replace('</span>',"")
    scraperSheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(price)
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("prices")
```

returns `null`. In other words, your spreadsheet hasn't a sheet named `prices`.

Double check if the argument of  the above code line is correct as well is your spreadsheet has the required structure and content.

NOTES:

The following image shows where goes the *spreadsheet name* and were goes the *sheet name*

[image]

Related

- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'pair' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62413580/1595451)

Comment: but i checked my spreadsheet name is "prices" .after that il get the error.....plz help me to find the error in my code properly.plz..!!

Comment: You are confusing spreadsheet with sheet, they aren't the same.

Comment: afer il get this error in my code     Exception: Request failed for https://www.amazon.in returned code 404. Truncated server response: <html dir="ltr">

Comment: @VIVEKSINGH Please post a new question.